# Pedometer in Android studio

Tags: android, android-sensors, pedometer

I'm trying to build a simple Step counter using sensor in android, I'm pretty sur the response is simple but actually i cant figure out

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor pedometer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    pedometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener, pedometer);
}


private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // Mettre à jour uniquement dans le cas de notre capteur
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            TextView txtpas = findViewById(R.id.Podometre);
            txtpas.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, pedometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}
```

}

Look simple but it actually never go to the sensorListener, someone know ?
Thank

Comment: Not all devices have a `TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` sensor. That could be one potential problem.

Comment: I was thinking about, but actually mine does